# Google add-on setting page uses a different script id

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I created a google calendar add-on and published it from the manifest and got the following URL:

`https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxmcjrwtjNMlXkB2I5xiJPBb-VYhU2bveiMGkFrPkdFjbJARusiDZswYaCDk-m6TDrl/exec`

(Copied from the deployment)

The problem is that Oauth2 and the settings page are broken because the script URL in Google calendar is different:

`https://script.google.com/a/mydomain.com/macros/s/AKfycbyy4AAzPl3smU-kdts89HQVaZiUFkFek-TyxwBi0FDsMHALscM/exec?settings`

Note that the URL scheme is also different, and especially the script id.
I've found this script id `AKfycbyy4AAzPl3smU-kdts89HQVaZiUFkFek-TyxwBi0FDsMHALscM` when I'm trying to deploy the add-on as a web app instead from manifest

What am I missing? How should I deploy the add-on to have the script Ids matching?

Edit: Apprently it's the call to `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();` which returns a different URL than the deployment URL. I do not know what this new URL is, and previous deployments did show that this API call return the same deployment URL.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Script ID go to File > Project properties

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The issue is with `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()`, which is NOT returning the actual script id URL, but another one. No idea why though.